# How to fix parameter missing after creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on subscribing application but I've been stacking with creating subscription on the show/page of product. Because of the error

> ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: subscription):

**routes.rb**

```
resources :products do
  resources :subscriptions, only: [:create]
end
```

**products/show.html.erb**

```
  <div class="subscribe">
    <%= form_with(model: @subscription, url: product_subscriptions_path(product_id: @product.id)) do |f| %>
      <div>
        <%= f.text_field :email %>
        <%= f.submit "Register", class: "btn"%>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

**products_controller.rb**

```
def show
  @product = Product.find_by_id(params[:id])
  @subscription = Subscription.new
end
```

**subscription_controller.rb**

```
def create
  @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
  @subscription = @product.subscriptions.build(create_params)
  @subscription.save
end

def create_params
  params.require(:subscription).permit(:email, :product_id)
end
```

Comment: Maybe `create_params` requires `subscription` but can't find it. What controller/line is producing the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The url helper needs two parameters here, as it is a [nested route.](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources)

```
url: product_subscriptions_path(product: @product, subscription: @subscription))
```